# EDA software (IC design)

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20130290834, eda, ic

Looking for prior art on this:

http://www.google.com/patents/US20130290834

Best answered by IC design people who use that kind of software.

Basically looking for what's in the main figure, two windows showing two different layers that represent adjacent dies. So, when a change is made to the top one for example, the effects on the other are made and shown in the second window.

Comment: This application is listed as "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 01-22-2018.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here is a general answer.

Depending on location, there are several *Patent and Trademark Resource Centers (PTRC)* across the U. S.. I remember the Sunnyvale Public Library used to be a PTRC. They had computers with direct access to the USPTO databases. Searching for prior art was something I could do very quickly. I came out with a list of 30 related and not-so-related patents in 90 minutes. You can find more about the centers in [this USPTO link](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/patent-and-trademark-resource-centers-ptrcs), including [PTRC locations](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/patent-and-trademark-resource-centers-ptrc/ptrc-locations). The computers at the PTRC were ready to go and the GUI easy to use. I bet you can do the same via a [USPTO search](http://patft.uspto.gov) but I can't confirm if the format is the same. There you can find both patents and filled applications. Consider [WIPO - Search International and National Patent Collections](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf) to find international patents.

I've seen the scholars are somewhat divorced from the patent system and they barely mention one or the other. The references are always either scholar in papers or patents in patents.  Therefore, I also recommend looking into School research papers. You can find quite a bit of information on the "linked in of research" [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/). A great source for prior art are school papers. [Science Direct](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf) has scientific publications. Finally, there is [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com).

Comment: It is rather easier to search patents on any computer using free resources such as Google Patents or The Lens or any of several other sites. In particular, this question is looking for prior art which includes non-patent materials. The USPTO is pretty good at searching for prior art in its own patent files. It is less good about finding other sources of prior art.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include this additional information. You might also want to include Google Scholar.

Comment: I incorporated comments and suggestions by editing the answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately the point of a prior art request is for people skilled in the field to provide references to relevant prior art. Your answer doesn't do that. Patent examiners are pretty good at reviewing older patents as prior art. What they don't always do if look for non-patent prior art.

Comment: Agreed, the don't always look is non-patent prior art. I even think, they never do. Nonetheless, intuition tells me that if non-patent prior art is available to the public, and to a person skilled in the art, before a patent is granted, that could become an objection on a court case. But, I don't know for sure. Does anyone know?

In regards to patent offices, it's usually enough to convey a search on patent databases.